# Converting Objective-C POST Request to Swift

Tags: objective-c, json, swift, post, server

I am new to Swift and don't know Objective C. I want to convert this function fully to Swift.

```
void post_req()

    {
        NSString *oper = @"99";
        NSString *key = @"22";
NSString *query = @"22";
NSString *event_id = @"2";
NSError * error = nil;

NSString *myRequestString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"operation=%@&key=%@&payload=%@", oper, key, query, event_id];
NSData *myRequestData = [ NSData dataWithBytes: [ myRequestString UTF8String ] length: [ myRequestString length ] ];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [ [ NSMutableURLRequest alloc ] initWithURL: [ NSURL URLWithString:@"numbers"]];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];
NSError *e = nil;
NSData *jData = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

id<NSObject> value = JSON[@"response"];

NSLog(@"responseData: %@", JSON);
NSLog(@"payData: %@", value);
NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];

if ([content isEqualToString:responseString])
{
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", content);
}
```

This is what I have so far. It isn't running properly.

```
func post_req() {

    let oper = "99"
    let key = "22"
    let query = "22"
    let event_id = "10"
    var error : NSError?

    let urlString = "http://numbers"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    var myRequestString = NSString(format: "operation=%@&key=%@&payload=%@", oper, key, query, event_id)
    var myRequestData = NSData(bytes: myRequestString.UTF8String, length: myRequestString.length)
    //request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField:"content-type")
    request.HTTPBody = myRequestData

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        var content = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        var jData = content.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        do {

            let JSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jData!, options: .MutableContainers)


            print("responseData: %@", JSON)

        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
        print("responseData: %@", content)

    })
    task.resume() 
}
```

I think the issues are occurring in at the end of the request, with the encoding but I just wanted to include all the details.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use Alamofire. It handles the jSon by default. We need not care about it. Just integrate the library to your project. Heres the instructions to do so: github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

use "import Alamofire" to import the library to your class. And then use the following code:

```
let parameters = ["oper": "99" ,"key" : "22" , "query" : "22" , "event_id" : "2" , "error" : "" ]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://yoururl.com", parameters: parameters)
 .responseString { response in
     print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
 }
 .responseJSON { response in
     print("Response JSON: \(response.result.value)")
   //Handle the json response here
  if let parseJSON = response.result.value {

        }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work. It's returning the same error as my own request.  This is the response:                                                                         { status code: 500, headers {
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Wed, 30 Mar 2016 20:18:10 GMT";
    Server = localhost;
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
} })